# Thecus N8800Pro drive numbers

Tags: network-attached-storage

We've a Thecus N8800Pro and need to replace one of the drives. Problem is I don't know how the drives are numbered. If I pop the wrong one I'll kill the already degraded RAID. Are the drives numbered vertically or horizontally:

```
1 x 2      1 x 6
3 4 5  or  2 4 7
6 7 8      3 5 8
```

FWIW I've RTFM to death and can't find the answer.

For bonus points is there a way of getting the unit to turn on the drive LED for identification purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kindly got a response from Thecus support:

```
1 x 6
2 4 7
3 5 8
```

[image: Thecus N8800Pro drive bay numbers]